# Extract string from Array php

Tags: php, arrays, variables

In my code, I am executing a statement that looks like this:

```
$welcomeMsg = $result->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

When I echo $welcomeMsg, I get Array.

However, this is essentially a query that was executed to retrieve a string. How can I format it such that I am displaying the string in the array?

Comment: What does the array look like? (You can use [`var_dump`](http://de2.php.net/var_dump) to display information about its structure and contents).

Comment: `fetchall` (which should probably be [`fetchAll()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)) returns an array, not a string. It returns an array of *all* the rows found. The parameter (`PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`), tells it what kind of array to return for each row, in your case an associative array. `$welcomeMsg` is actually a 2D array. It looks like this: `[['field'=>'value'],['field'=>'value2']]`. You need to loop over `$welcomeMsg` and get the fields for each row. If you only returned one row don't use `fetchAll`, use [`fetch()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php).

Comment: @RocketHazmat, why the micro efficiency of not using 'fetchAll' 'cos you know only one row will be returned? i.e. what are the benefits of not doing 'fetchAll'? Are timings available that demonstrate it is worthwhile doing 'fetch' rather than 'fetchAll? I am curious and not being 'awkward'.

Comment: @RyanVincent: I'm not worrying about efficiency, I'm trying to help a user who seems confused.  I figure that `fetch()` might be easier for him.

Comment: @RocketHazmat, makes sense. I misunderstood what you trying to explain.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
print_r($welcomeMsg);
```

to see what is in the Array;

and then use the suitable index to get the string.

Answer (score 0):

Use `print_r()` -

```
$welcomeMsg = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo '<!--<pre>'; print_r($welcomeMsg); echo '</pre>-->';
```

You can view the array in `view source`, hence it also won't disturb your html view and allows you to debug easily.

And for extracting the string from the array, you can use `foreach loop`.

```
foreach($welcomeMsg as $msg)
{
    $msg[key] = value;
}
```

Comment: `print_r` should *only* be used as a debugging tool.